# Retorno de valores incorretos do banco ao preeencher uma JTable

Tags: java

Tenho uma Classe Cadastro, que é responsável pela View. Nela tenho esse código:

```
public void listarTabela(){
    DefaultTableModel val = (DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel();
    val.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    UsuarioDAO usDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    List<Usuario> usuarios = usDAO.listarUsuarios();
    int i = 0;
    while(usuarios.size() > i){
        val.addRow(new Object[] {String.valueOf(usuarios.get(i).getId()), usuarios.get(i).getNome(),
            usuarios.get(i).getCpf(), usuarios.get(i).getEmail(), usuarios.get(i).getTelefone()});
        i++;
```

Na classe UsuarioDAO(classe responsável pelos tratamentos sql que cada botão da view tera executando), tenho o código:

```
public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios(){
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
   ResultSet rs;
   List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
   try{
       PreparedStatement stmt = conecta.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = stmt.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()){
           Usuario us = new Usuario();
           us.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
           us.setNome("nome");
           us.setEmail("email");
           us.setCpf("cpf");
           us.setTelefone("telefone");
           usuarios.add(us);
       }
       rs.close();
       stmt.close();
       return usuarios;
   }catch(SQLException e){
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

Tenho também uma JTable e um JButton, que chama `listarTabela();`. Toda vez que eu clico no botão, mesmo que eu chame no construtor da classe, em qualquer momento que eu chame o "`listarTabela()`" ela me retorna na JTable:

> 1,nome,cpf,email,telefone
>   2,nome,cpf,email,telefone
>   3,nome,cpf,email,telefone

O banco de dados esta ok, ele retorna os valores corretos.

Comment: Por favor acesse o link e forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: O que está faltando ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há um exemplo verificável na pergunta mas ao que tudo indica, você não está resgatando valores das colunas corretamente.

Observe este trecho:

```
   rs = stmt.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()){
       Usuario us = new Usuario();
       us.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
       us.setNome("nome");
       us.setEmail("email");
       us.setCpf("cpf");
       us.setTelefone("telefone");
       usuarios.add(us);
   }
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
```

Você popula o objeto `Usuario` com strings que, suponho eu, seja o nomes das colunas da tabela do seu banco. A forma correta de fazer isso é através do [`Resultset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) e seus métodos `getXXXX` onde esse XXXX é o tipo a ser resgatado.

Um exemplo, caso os tipo de todas as colunas da sua tabela sejam String:

```
   rs = stmt.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()){
       Usuario us = new Usuario();
       us.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
       us.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
       us.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
       us.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
       us.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
       usuarios.add(us);
   }
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
```

Exceto a coluna `id` que estava certa, demais colunas vão tentar recuperar um tipo String. Caso o tipo retornado de alguma das colunas não seja String, consulte na documentação da classe o método getXXXX adequado para o tipo retornado por ela.

Comment: Muito obrigado !! Funcionou !!!

Comment: @PedroAnselmo lembrando que você pode concluir a pergunta, aceitando a resposta clicando no `v` ao lado.

Comment: Inclusive eu estou tentando fazer isso, só não entendi como ainda, Sou novo por aqui.